# Gas-Phase Functionalization of Carbon Nanotubes

Tags: carbon-allotropes

I'm new to the subject of carbon nanotubes; However, I recently studied a little about them. But I failed to understand the gas phase functionalization.

As I understand, this technique is used to improve the solubility of the nanotubes.

However, I failed to understand the chemistry and physics of these processes so resumidad, considering that there have been many experiments in this field, but I failed to understand the basis of this process.

Someone could explain?

Another question: What causes that the nanotubes are hydrophobic?